# How to use stripe library in android for payment

Tags: android

I am working on app where i need to implement payment method like paypal or stripe ,I want to implement stripe but i have no idea of that.Can somebody tell me step by step that how to integrate android app with stripe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have [pretty good documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android) on their website and [the library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android) on GitHub.

If you are using Android Studio and you don't see anything about it on the doc website, check out the GitHub library. The gradle lib should be

```
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+'
```

Comment: i m using ADT ..i have read the documentation but i have confusion ..i want to know is i have to create extra classes to use it or simply import the stripe lib into my project

Comment: Simply import the lib. They have an [example app](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/tree/master/example) in their lib as well.